# Python: UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 3-4: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, ftfy

I found a site which fixes my mojibake, [here](https://ftfy.now.sh/) that uses the python package [ftfy](https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/). I tried reproducing the steps given, although it seems to pre-convert the string before running the steps it gives me.

The string I am trying to fix is `EvðŸ’ðŸ‘¸ðŸ»`, although the site seems to pre-convert it to `EvÃ°Å¸â\x80\x99Â\x9dÃ°Å¸â\x80\x98Â¸Ã°Å¸Â\x8fÂ»` before attempting to fix it with the same steps as I am below.

**My question is**, how can I get my string in the same state as the site, before running the `fix_broken_unicode` function, to hopfully avoid the error I am facing?

When running my script, (probably due to me not pre-converting) I receive:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 3-4: ordinal not in range(256)`

The source code for mentioned website can be found at: https://github.com/simonw/ftfy-web/blob/master/ftfy_app.py, although because I am primarily a C++ developer I can't understand it.

My script:

```
import ftfy.bad_codecs 

def fix_broken_unicode(string):
    string = string.encode('latin-1')
    string = string.decode('utf-8')
    string = string.encode('sloppy-windows-1252')
    string = string.decode('utf-8')
    return string
    
print(fix_broken_unicode("EvðŸ’ðŸ‘¸ðŸ»"))
```

Updates since answer:

My input: `"EvðŸ’ðŸ‘¸ðŸ»"`, expected outcome: `Ev`

Answer (score 1):

Your data string might be missing some non-printable characters:

```
>>> s = 'EvðŸ’\x9dðŸ‘¸ðŸ\x8f»'  # \x9d and \x8f aren't printable.
>>> print(s)                    # This looks like your mojibake.
EvðŸ’ðŸ‘¸ðŸ»
>>> s.encode('mbcs').decode('utf8')
'Ev'
```

Note that Python's `mbcs` codec corresponds to Windows default ANSI codec.
It matches "sloppy-windows1252" only if `Windows-1252` is the default ANSI codec (US- and Western European-localized versions of Windows), which is what I am running.

The other option is your original UTF-8 data was decoded with `.decode('cp1252',errors='ignore')`.  If this is the case the two bytes were lost and the string isn't reversible.